# trying to cut off at the last character that's a space

Tags: php

I need to find out where the last character in the string is where the charachter is a space, and cut it off there. This is the function I'm using, but there seems to be something wrong with the if statement, but I can't figure out what. There is certainly a space in the $text-string.

Let's say I have a string "Hey, my name is Joh". Then it has to be shortened to "Hey, my name is ".

```
$checkLastChar = false;
$text = $line[2];

while($checkLastChar != true){
   for($i = 1; $i <= strlen($text); $i++)
    {
        if($text[strlen($tekst) - $i] == " ") {
                $checkLastChar = true;
            $text = substr($text, 1, strlen($text) - $i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so how many characters you want to cut?

Comment: That's going to depend on the string, sometimes it can be 1, other times 5.

Comment: Here's how you will do it. Think of a pattern in which the string to be cut will come. Withhout a definite pattern, it is impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, ' '));
```

Answer (score 3):

<s>Why don't you use [`rtrim()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)?</s>

**update**

Based on the clarification [a solution like Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10500457/250259)'s seems to be more appropriate.

Comment: Well it's not always the last character, it can be the third last or something, and then it has to be shortened until that character. I'll update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: This answer does actually what you asked for. Be clear next time from the start.

Comment: I think he doesn't just want the space removed, I thinks he wants every character that comes after the space to be removed as well.

Comment: well he is changing his questions with each edit. Not fair for the people who are trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered using [trim()](http://lv.php.net/trim)? It strips the spaces from beginning AND end.

Example:

```
echo trim(' Hello my name is Matt.  ');
```

Comment: trim cuts from both begining and ending.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$str = "dsajhc   \tsjdtgsd   "; // string with whitespaces
$str = preg_replace( '/(\s+.*)/i', '', $str ); // remove everything after whitespace
?>
```

Hope it helps.